# Magento - Display Category information in Sales Orders view

Tags: php, magento

EDIT: So a guy in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2489572/sales-by-category-in-magento) says the following: 
"All order data in Magento is product-specific. It doesn't store anything about what category the products are in. So, as you have found out, there are no reports available in Magento for that sort of thing."
Is this true?  Is what I am trying to do a lost cause?

I am trying to display product categories on Magento's backend Sales > Order > specific order view > Information > Items Ordered grid.  This is not the main "Orders grid" that you see when navigating to Sales > Order.  I want to alter the more detailed one that you see after clicking on a specific order in that first grid.

Following advice from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958965/adding-new-column-in-sales-order-view-items-in-magento-admin), I've made a new column and given it the proper title (Categories).

Then, to try to populate that column, I added code from Joost de Valk's solution on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009861/how-do-i-get-categories-for-a-product-in-magento) to app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/items/renderer/default.phtml

I feel like I should be close (or not) but currently that code is just returning the word "Array".  Any thoughts?

My current code is below.  The column in question is the second td - the one that echoes $cats:

```
<?php $_item = $this->getItem() ?>
// Here is the snippet I pasted in to define variables.
<?php $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);

$cats = $product->getCategoryIds();
foreach ($cats as $category_id) {
    $_cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id) ;
    echo $_cat->getName();
}  ?>
<?php $this->setPriceDataObject($_item) ?>
<tr<?php if (!$this->canDisplayGiftmessage()): ?> class="border"<?php endif; ?>>
    <td>
        <?php if ($this->canDisplayContainer()): ?>
        <div id="<?php echo $this->getHtmlId() ?>" class="item-container">
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="item-text">
            <?php echo $this->getColumnHtml($_item, 'name') ?>
        </div>
        <?php if ($this->canDisplayContainer()): ?>
        </div>
        <?php endif ?>
    </td>
// Here is the column in question.
    <td class="a-center"><?php echo $cats ?></td>
    <td class="a-center"><?php echo $_item->getStatus() ?></td>
    <td class="a-right"><?php echo $this->displayPriceAttribute('original_price') ?></td>

etc, etc, etc ...
```

Comment: `<td class="a-center"><?php echo $cats ?></td>` -> `$cats` is an array. What exactly do you want from it?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Well, I want product categories, ultimately.  But I am very new to php, so I am not even sure whether the variable I define ($cats = $product->getCategoryIds() etc) contains the information I need...  I guess there is no standard call in Magento for product categories?

Answer (score 1):

`$_cat` is an object

```
$_cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id) ;

<td class="a-center"><?php echo $cats ?></td>
```

You need to know which property you want to display

```
echo $_cat->getXyz();
```

eg.

```
echo $_cat->getName();
```

To see a list of some of it properties try

```
print_r($_cat->getData());
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is helpful. Where would I enter that print_r command to see a list of properties?

Comment: In the foreach loop just after `echo $_cat->getName();` should do. It will call print_r for each category but that doesn't really matter since you are just exploring now

Comment: What info are you trying to display about you category?

Comment: Yes I definitely will.  I am trying to display category name.  Apologies for my complete lack of knowledge of PHP and the print_r command, but do I then need to call print_r somehow?  If I just enter it in the foreach loop at Ossie7 says and then refresh the page, nothing changes.

Comment: Okay, figured something out... I entered the print_r line where Ossie7 mentioned and then called it with `<?php echo'<pre>';
print_r($cats);
echo '</pre>'; ?>` in the column section.  Now the column returns "Array ( )"  Does this mean the variable has no properties?

Comment: Also the `print_r($_cat)` leaves the column completely blank.

Comment: Wait, does anyone know whether this is this possible at all?  I edited the original question at top to include a link to a place where a fellow says that Magento isn't storing category info when it makes a sale.  Any comments on that claim?

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that categories are really complicated and certainly beyond my abilities.  I figured out a work-around, however ugly.  Since I am not using the manufacturer field and have only 4 relevant categories, I am creating "manufacturers" for each of those 4 categories, going through and assigning them to all products, and then calling for manufacturer in the relevant file.  The code for manufacturer is as follows:

```
 <?php 
$manufacturer = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item['product_id'])->getAttributeText('manufacturer'); 
echo $manufacturer;
?>
```

Thanks to [this post](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/193770/#t242317) for that snippet and thanks to everyone else for their help.